# Send canvas image data (Uint8ClampedArray) to Flask Server via Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, html5-canvas

I'd like to send image data on an HTML5  to a flask server back-end via AJAX. I extract the relevant image data from the  using `context.getImageData(a, b, c, d)`, and would ideally like to have access to that data as a numpy array on my flask backend. How might I best go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A successful (although perhaps not optimally efficient) method for dealing with this is to

1. Put the imageData onto a canvas (`context.putImageData`)
2. Create a data URL from this canavs (`canvas.toDataURL`)
3. Send this data URL to the server as base64
4. Do some conversion work on the python side to get it into numpy shape

### Client-Side (JS)

```
var scratchCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = scratchCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.putImageData(...);
var dataURL = scratchCanvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://url/hook",
  data:{
    imageBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function() {
  console.log('sent');
});
```

### Server-Side (Python/Flask)

```
# ... Flask imports above ...
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import base64
import re
import cStringIO

@app.route('/hook', methods=['POST'])
def get_image():
    image_b64 = request.values['imageBase64']
    image_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', image_b64).decode('base64')
    image_PIL = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(image_b64))
    image_np = np.array(image_PIL)
    print 'Image received: {}'.format(image_np.shape)
    return ''
```

Comment: Could you explain the need for image_data variable. It’s initialized and never used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The "Server-Side (Python/Flask)" setup from user1907180 is outdated and should be:

```py
# ... Flask imports above ...

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import json
import re

@app.route('/hook', methods=['POST'])
def save_canvas():
    image_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', request.form['imageBase64'])
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_data)))
    # im.save('canvas.png')
    return json.dumps({'result': 'success'}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
```