# How to send canvas data from javascript to django with ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am working on a django application where the user can trigger the webcam and capture a photo. This photo is saved in a canvas. I want to send this image to django views, through which, the image can be saved inside the django server.

I am using webrtc to trigger the webcam. I was having a hard time saving the data with js itself and read somewhere that this is not possible with js alone. So I am now trying to send te data to python using ajax but am not able to. I am a beginner with working with canvas and ajax so, a detailed explanation will be helpful.

I tried working with these answers, but none of them seemed to help

[Send canvas image data (Uint8ClampedArray) to Flask Server via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957490/send-canvas-image-data-uint8clampedarray-to-flask-server-via-ajax)

[Can't send data back to Django from JS AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493940/cant-send-data-back-to-django-from-js-ajax)

here is my code so far

**html template**

```
<center>
    <button type="button" name="button" class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg' id='start'>Start Video Capture</button>

    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video><br>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#image_model" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</center>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Retake</button>
<form action="{% url 'img_submit' %}" method="post" class="image_submit_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Use Image" class="btn btn-primary" id="use_image">
</form>
```

Not sure if a form is needed for `use_image` to send data to python.

**javascript code**

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get access to the camera!
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(function(stream) {
            //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }

    $('#snap').fadeIn();

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        $("#use_image").click(function() {
            let $form = $(".image_submit_form");
            let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataURL),
                data: {
                    imageBase64: dataURL
                }
            }).done(function() {
                console.log('sent');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

I am pretty sure I have messed up the ajax part.

I still have not written any code to save the image with python, but I am guess that will be easy if I can somehow convert the canvas data to a jpeg or png and then send it to python. I also did not understand why we have to convert canvas data to base64. Cant we just convert that to png?

Please help me.
Thank you

## [EDIT1]

**python views.py**

```
def img_submit(request):
    url = request.POST.dict()
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending the rgba pixels array to django views with ajax. 
In your case, the code would like:

```
        var data_pixel = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480).data;
        $("#use_image").click(function() {
        let $form = $(".image_submit_form");
        let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'image': JSON.stringify(data_pixel),
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data['response']);
            });
        });
```

Besides, add below scripts to avoid the csrf_token after ajax

```
// csrf code
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
```

In views:

```
def img_submit(request):
    data_image = request.POST.get('image')
    data_image_parse = json.loads(data_image) # parse JSON.stringify and would be a dictionary
    data_image = list(data_image_parse.values()) # convert to list and would be length of 640 * 480 * 4
    image = np.array(data_image).reshape(480, 640, 4) # here is your image data and you can save it
    response = {}
    response['response'] = 'whatever you want to say' 
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Notice that the django has DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE of 2.5MB but you can change this default in settings.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you code works fine but this is critical :

```
 ...


            data: JSON.stringify(dataURL),
            data: {
                imageBase64: dataURL
            }
```

You cant create object with two same key access.
Even no need to inject twice time same data.

Remove JSON.stringify line and then try again!  I already done this with websocket i don't see reason for not working!

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K ...

Also try :

```
.toDataURL("image/png")
```

Check connection did work.

Post full errors log ! Maybe you have permission bugs if you wanna do it programmability with no user request (click).

I fount it !

```
var dataURL = "I Need to be global";

document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function(){

            // WORK ON CLICK    
            ...
           dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();


            // ATTACHING EVENT - NO CALL 
            $("#use_image").click(function() {
               // This will work only on click again on use_image
            })
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. right now the output of this code is `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. I have edited the question to add the django views.py as well.

Comment: I am not sure, how to convert the canvas data to jpeg or png and then send it to python. please help me with that.

Comment: If your dataURL is undefined then i found you bug

Comment: I dont seem to be getting any errors with my code. But the problem is that it is not returning anything to python

Comment: try console.log(dataURL) before use or use debugger to see real values in moment of ajax...You must be sure!